# How to render component with ajax in react native?

Tags: react-native

My code is

```
const main = () => {
  let caption;
  AsyncStorage.getItem("XXX", (err, result) => {
    caption = <View>...</View>  
  });
  render (
  ...
    {caption}
  ...
  );
}
```

But I got an error as below.

> RawText "" must be wrapped in an explicit `<Text>` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that, based on your pseudo-code, you understand how to get data from `AsyncStorage`, that it's *not a good idea* to be using `AsyncStorage` inside your `render` function, and that you don't actually mean ajax but rather local storage.

But the error is showing up because you need to make sure you wrap text inside a `<Text>` element. If you look at [this paragraph](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#limited-style-inheritance) it says:

> In React Native, we are more strict about it: you must wrap all the text nodes inside of a `<Text>` component; you cannot have a text node directly under a `<View>`.

**EDIT**:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('XXX', (err, result) => {
      // @TODO: You should handle errors too
      this.setState({
        data: result.text,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    // Returning null will not render anything
    // Once the results come in, it will update automatically
    if (!this.state.data) return null;
    // Raw text must be wrapped in Text
    return (
      <Text>{this.state.data}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a just simple code.
You can suppose AsyncStorage likes a async call.
I need how to render component in call back function after async calling is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to stock data in a state and display your component whit a function:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("XXX", (err, result) => {
    this.setState({result:result})
});

function element(){
    if([check if your state is not null])
    return(
         <View>... {this.state.result} ...</View>
    )
}

render (
  ...
    {this.element()}
  ...
);
```